# Best tool to search large drives for file content?

Tags: search, text, drives

EDIT:
Ok So I found an indexing tool [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) but it is half what I may need. Is there a tool that does the powerful indexing of "Everything" and provides a PowerGrep like search also?

### Thanks

I am a bit lost in trying to find the best known tool for searching file(s) for some specific content. Since I have multiple drives and the data size ranges from 1TB to 100TB, I was wondering if there are some robust tools that can do a hard drive search.

One tool that I found was PowerGrep, on a small test for 23GB of data, it took about 11 minutes to find a string in a specific file. This would be reasonably fast for some, but is there something better?

I know that performance would be well affected depending upon the folder structures, drive configuration etc.

Is this the right approach or is there an extra step involved in file searching that is required?

Thanks for the precious input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[dtSearch](http://dtsearch.com) is the tool that I found
- Does indexing
- Search times typically less than a second
- Distributed search across network
- indexing option include import, merge of different indices.
- simple GUI
- Phonetics, semantic, fuzzy searching
- Developer API
- Well known formates supported including archives
- Indexes well for unknown format by treating them as binary